# Qt draws text with otf font outside the element

Tags: c++, qt, fonts

Today I switched the font of my application from one of the standard system fonts to Sinkin in the form of an otf file, I've added to my `resource.qrc`.

The following code sets the default font of the application object.

```
int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/font.otf");
QString family = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0);
qapp.setFont(family);

QFont font = qapp.font();
font.setPointSize(opt_font_size);
qapp.setFont(font);
```

Now it seems, that the font is placed a bit too high in all elements. That means buttons, labels, input fields and tabs. Or Qt does not realize, that it has to adjust the size of the elements to fit the new font.

Changing the font size via `setPointSize` does not fix it. Everything just gets smaller or bigger.

Any ideas where I can dig into?

[image: Example]

Comment: I think Qt miscalculates the text size.... A workaround would be to set [padding](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#padding-prop).

Comment: Is it otf specific? Does it work correctly with ttf?

Comment: @user1810087 I will try `padding` tomorrow, but would prefer a different solution. It will run on embedded devices and I have negative experience with qt-css and perfomance.

Comment: @agilob Also tomorrow, I will download some more otf and ttf fonts for comparison...